# Window Hiding Layout/object mode

Tags: scene, windows

As I was trying to work on my model, I accidentally pulled a window over my layout/thing I was working on and now I can't figure out how to close it. I tried reopening the file but it presented me with the same issue.
Thank you
[image: The Info bar thing hiding the layout]

Answer (score 0):

In the top-left corner of any area, you can see this button:

[image: editor switch]

Click it to open the editor list, and chose any editor you want for that area.

Answer (score 0):

Every window that you open have an "Editor Type" menu

[image]

Just click that and select 3D Viewport